# Outlook 2013 won't start except Exchange Cache Mode is active

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, windows-server-2012-r2, rds

I do have a strange problem:

Yesterday I logged off from my RDS 2012 R2 session. until that point I had no issues with Outlook.

Today I logged into a new RDS 2012 R2 session and tried to start Outlook.

First, I was prompted to enter my credentials - which I never had to do before then Outlook starting failed with error Message:

Cannot start Microsoft Outlook. Cannot open the Outlook window. The set of folders cannot be opened. Microsoft Exchange is not available. Either there are network problems or the Exchange server is down for maintenance

No Outlook window appeared.

Then a I tried a lot things - all failed with same message:

- tried again, immediately :)
- logged off, logged on
- tried another user on RDS - works like a charm
- tried 3 more users on RDS - none of those had a problem
- tried to connect to Outlook through a local PC with OL2013 - works as well
- tried to connect to Outlook from a laptop with OL2010 - works as well

I turned on "Cached Exchange Mode" and the error was gone! Immediately I turned it off and tried again - same error! Turned Cached Exchange Mode on - error gone!

therefor I assume there must be something wrong with my RDS user profile as I am the only user having issues on the server session and my local Outlook work without a hazzle.

So the next step I took were:

- rebooting the Domain Controller
- rebooting the Exchange server
- rebooting the RDS Server

Still same issue. So next steps

- deleted the Outlook Profile and created a new one
- deleted the Outlook Profile and all sub folders in appdata\roaming|local\Outlook
- I've changed my Active Directory Password

Still same issue.

I can only connect with Cached Exchange Mode on - with turned off, I get the error above!

I'm out of things to try - except deleting my RDS User Profile which will be the ultimate solutions. But I will loose so many settings!

There must be an issue with the Cached Exchange Mode. As it works if turn on - which never was and none other user has turned on.

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For further troubleshooting, I want to confirm something with you:

Does the issue only occur to this issue? Does the problematic user work well in OWA?

In addition, here are some troubleshooting steps for your reference:

1. Run outlook in safe mode and check if there are some add-ins cause the issue.
2. Refer to: [I can’t start Microsoft Outlook or receive the error “Cannot start Microsoft Outlook. Cannot open the Outlook Window”](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/i-can-t-start-microsoft-outlook-or-receive-the-error-cannot-start-microsoft-outlook-cannot-open-the-outlook-window-d1f69da6-b333-4650-97bf-4d77bd7abb85)

Comment: Thanks for helping out! As I stated, only 1 user is affected and only when using Outlook within a RDS session. Other Outlooks connected to Exchange or OWA work fine.

I've already started outlook in safe mode and I've already deleted and created a new Outlook Profile - none helped. I've as well already stumbled open your link before I wrote this question - nothing helps.

And now, I'm having the same issue again!